# Can I force a background image to stay for a certain length of time after the element is active?

Tags: css, animation, background-image, css-animations

I am designing a website theme in which I can only change the CSS, not the JavaScript or HTML source. There is a `div` element (not a link) that I want to show an APNG (like an animated GIF) background image when clicked. The problem is that the `div` doesn't remain active after the mouse button is up, so the animation doesn't usually get a chance to play through. Is there a way to prevent the background from going back to its normal state until after a delay?

I thought maybe a CSS `@keyframe` animation would work, but I'm not sure. The image is just an expanding gradient, so the image could be replaced with that (I think the image is easier because gradients aren't animatable either.

Answer (score 0):

You can fake a click and **keep** the change 'active' by using a very long transition and adjusting the transition-delay on the initial and `:active` states.

```css
.box {
  width:100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin: 1rem auto;
  background-color: #f00;
  transition-property: background-color;
  transition-duration: 9999s;
}

/*.box:hover,*/
.box:active {
  background-color: #00f;
  transition-duration: 0;
  transition-delay: 0s;
  transition-timing-function: linear;

}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```